# where do I add this echo shortcode line inside the php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an account settings page and I want its content password protected.

There's a plugin to password protect a content using a shortcode call Passster.

The problem is the account settings page is like an endpoint so I need to add the shortcode inside the php file. The url looks something like website.com/members/name/settings

This is the php code I'm looking at

```
<?php
/**
* BuddyBoss Settings Loader.
*
* @package BuddyBoss\Settings\Loader
* @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
*/
```

```
// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Creates our Settings component.
 *
 * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
 */
class BP_Settings_Component extends BP_Component {

    /**
     * Start the settings component creation process.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::start(
            'settings',
            __( 'Account', 'buddyboss' ),
            buddypress()->plugin_dir,
            array(
                'adminbar_myaccount_order' => 21,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Include files.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
     *
     * @param array $includes Array of values to include. Not used.
     */
    public function includes( $includes = array() ) {
        parent::includes(
            array(
                'template',
                'functions',
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Late includes method.
     *
     * Only load up certain code when on specific pages.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 3.0.0
     */
    public function late_includes() {
        // Bail if PHPUnit is running.
        if ( defined( 'BP_TESTS_DIR' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Bail if not on Settings component.
        if ( ! bp_is_settings_component() ) {
            return;
        }

        $actions = array( 'notifications', 'capabilities', 'delete-account', 'export' );

        // Authenticated actions.
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( ! bp_current_action() || bp_is_current_action( 'general' ) ) {
                require $this->path . 'bp-settings/actions/general.php';

                // Specific to post requests.
            } elseif ( bp_is_post_request() && in_array( bp_current_action(), $actions, true ) ) {
                require $this->path . 'bp-settings/actions/' . bp_current_action() . '.php';
            }
        }

        // Screens - User profile integration.
        if ( bp_is_user() ) {
            require $this->path . 'bp-settings/screens/general.php';

            // Sub-nav items.
            if ( in_array( bp_current_action(), $actions, true ) ) {
                require $this->path . 'bp-settings/screens/' . bp_current_action() . '.php';
            }
        }
    }
    


    /**
     * Setup globals.
     *
     * The BP_SETTINGS_SLUG constant is deprecated, and only used here for
     * backwards compatibility.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
     *
     * @param array $args Array of arguments.
     */
    
    public function setup_globals( $args = array() ) {

        // Define a slug, if necessary.
        if ( ! defined( 'BP_SETTINGS_SLUG' ) ) {
            define( 'BP_SETTINGS_SLUG', $this->id );
        }

        // All globals for settings component.
        parent::setup_globals(
            array(
                'slug'          => BP_SETTINGS_SLUG,
                'has_directory' => false,
            )
        );
    }
    

    /**
     * Set up navigation.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
     *
     * @param array $main_nav Array of main nav items.
     * @param array $sub_nav  Array of sub nav items.
     */
    public function setup_nav( $main_nav = array(), $sub_nav = array() ) {

        // Determine user to use.
        if ( bp_displayed_user_domain() ) {
            $user_domain = bp_displayed_user_domain();
        } elseif ( bp_loggedin_user_domain() ) {
            $user_domain = bp_loggedin_user_domain();
        } else {
            return;
        }

        $access        = bp_core_can_edit_settings();
        $slug          = bp_get_settings_slug();
        $settings_link = trailingslashit( $user_domain . $slug );

        // Add the settings navigation item.
        $main_nav = array(
            'name'                    => __( 'Account', 'buddyboss' ),
            'slug'                    => $slug,
            'position'                => 21,
            'show_for_displayed_user' => $access,
            'screen_function'         => 'bp_settings_screen_general',
            'default_subnav_slug'     => 'general',
        );

        // Add General Settings nav item.
        $sub_nav[] = array(
            'name'            => __( 'Login Information', 'buddyboss' ),
            'slug'            => 'general',
            'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
            'parent_slug'     => $slug,
            'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_general',
            'position'        => 10,
            'user_has_access' => $access,
        );

        // Add Email nav item. Formerly called 'Notifications', we
        // retain the old slug and function names for backward compat.
        $sub_nav[] = array(
            'name'            => __( 'Email Preferences', 'buddyboss' ),
            'slug'            => 'notifications',
            'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
            'parent_slug'     => $slug,
            'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_notification',
            'position'        => 20,
            'user_has_access' => $access,
        );

        $sub_nav[] = array(
            'name'            => __( 'Export Data', 'buddyboss' ),
            'slug'            => 'export',
            'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
            'parent_slug'     => $slug,
            'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_export_data',
            'position'        => 80,
            'user_has_access' => $access,
        );

        if( bp_is_active( 'moderation' ) && bp_is_moderation_member_blocking_enable() ){
            $sub_nav[] = array(
                'name'            => __( 'Blocked Members', 'buddyboss' ),
                'slug'            => 'blocked-members',
                'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
                'parent_slug'     => $slug,
                'screen_function' => 'bp_moderation_screen',
                'position'        => 65,
                'user_has_access' => $access,
            );
        }

        // Add Spam Account nav item.
        if ( bp_current_user_can( 'bp_moderate' ) ) {
            $sub_nav[] = array(
                'name'            => __( 'Capabilities', 'buddyboss' ),
                'slug'            => 'capabilities',
                'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
                'parent_slug'     => $slug,
                'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_capabilities',
                'position'        => 80,
                'user_has_access' => ! bp_is_my_profile(),
            );
        }

        // Add Delete Account nav item.
        if ( ( ! bp_disable_account_deletion() && bp_is_my_profile() ) || bp_current_user_can( 'delete_users' ) ) {
            $sub_nav[] = array(
                'name'            => __( 'Delete Account', 'buddyboss' ),
                'slug'            => 'delete-account',
                'parent_url'      => $settings_link,
                'parent_slug'     => $slug,
                'screen_function' => 'bp_settings_screen_delete_account',
                'position'        => 90,
                'user_has_access' => ! is_super_admin( bp_displayed_user_id() ),
            );
        }

        parent::setup_nav( $main_nav, $sub_nav );
    }

    /**
     * Set up the Toolbar.
     *
     * @since BuddyPress 1.5.0
     *
     * @param array $wp_admin_nav Array of Admin Bar items.
     */
    public function setup_admin_bar( $wp_admin_nav = array() ) {

        // Menus for logged in user.
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

            // Setup the logged in user variables.
            $settings_link = trailingslashit( bp_loggedin_user_domain() . bp_get_settings_slug() );

            // Add main Settings menu.
            $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                'parent' => buddypress()->my_account_menu_id,
                'id'     => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                'title'  => __( 'Account', 'buddyboss' ),
                'href'   => $settings_link,
            );

            // General Account.
            $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                'parent'   => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                'id'       => 'my-account-' . $this->id . '-general',
                'title'    => __( 'Login Information', 'buddyboss' ),
                'href'     => $settings_link,
                'position' => 10,
            );

            // Notifications - only add the tab when there is something to display there.
            if ( has_action( 'bp_notification_settings' ) ) {
                $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                    'parent'   => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                    'id'       => 'my-account-' . $this->id . '-notifications',
                    'title'    => __( 'Email Preferences', 'buddyboss' ),
                    'href'     => trailingslashit( $settings_link . 'notifications' ),
                    'position' => 20,
                );
            }

            $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                'parent'   => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                'id'       => 'my-account-' . $this->id . '-export',
                'title'    => __( 'Export Data', 'buddyboss' ),
                'href'     => trailingslashit( $settings_link . 'export/' ),
                'position' => 50,
            );

            // Delete Account
            if ( ! bp_current_user_can( 'bp_moderate' ) && ! bp_core_get_root_option( 'bp-disable-account-deletion' ) ) {
                $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                    'parent'   => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                    'id'       => 'my-account-' . $this->id . '-delete-account',
                    'title'    => __( 'Delete Account', 'buddyboss' ),
                    'href'     => trailingslashit( $settings_link . 'delete-account' ),
                    'position' => 90,
                );
            }

            if ( bp_is_active( 'moderation' ) && bp_is_moderation_member_blocking_enable() ) {
                // Blocked Members.
                $wp_admin_nav[] = array(
                    'parent'   => 'my-account-' . $this->id,
                    'id'       => 'my-account-' . $this->id . '-blocked-members',
                    'title'    => __( 'Blocked Members', 'buddyboss' ),
                    'href'     => trailingslashit( $settings_link . 'blocked-members/' ),
                    'position' => 31,
                );
            }
        }

        parent::setup_admin_bar( $wp_admin_nav );
    }


    /**
     * Init the BuddyBoss REST API.
     *
     * @param array $controllers Optional. See BP_Component::rest_api_init() for description.
     *
     * @since BuddyBoss 1.3.5
     */
    public function rest_api_init( $controllers = array() ) {
        parent::rest_api_init( array(
            'BP_REST_Account_Settings_Endpoint',
            'BP_REST_Account_Settings_Options_Endpoint',
        ) );
    }

}
```

I want to add this shortcode [passster password="123"]. This shortcode will password protect the content of this page, which is the account settings information. The closing shortcode is [/passster]

PLEASE HELP

Comment: The class you added is from a WordPress plugins settings page. It's very unlikely it got anything to do with the page you are writing about.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear what you really want with all that code, but to echo your WP shortcode from a php file, just use `echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123"]');`